# Can I add char limit to php/postgres pg_escape_string? If so how?

Tags: php, string, postgresql, char

I've this php code:

```
 $reg_number = strtoupper(pg_escape_string($_SESSION['regiter'][2]['serial']));
```

I need to set $reg_number field to max 10 char adding the limit to this string

Thank you if you provide me the code

**EDIT**

I need that $reg_number must equal to 10 or under 10 char. (in my postgres db the field is char limit to 10...sorry)

"cutted" results is ok

Comment: At which point do you need to impose the limit? Under no circumstance apply it to the result of `pg_escape_string` because results will be broken when you cut the string off in the middle of an escaped character. Please add more background info to the question

Comment: **Do not** mix database string escaping with anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reg_number = $_SESSION['regiter'][2]['serial']);
if( strlen($reg_number)>10 ){
    $reg_number = substr($reg_number, 0, 10);
}
$reg_number = pg_escape_string(strtoupper($reg_number));
```

Comment: @Pekka, you were right, I saw your comment after noticing myself and removing the answer.

Comment: There is no need to test the length of the string because substr returns the whole string if it is shorter than the limit.